# How do I change the size of a kendo popup edit screen and have all of the items in it resize to the new size?

Tags: kendo-ui

This is what the popup looks like now:

[image]

I want to make the actual popup bigger as well as all of the text boxes inside.

Apparently, this changes the size of the actual popup and then centers it on the screen, the problem now is that I don't know how to resize the text boxes inside. It is executed on the `EDIT` event of the grid:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
                $(".k-edit-form-container").parent().width(800).height(400).data("kendoWindow").center();
            }, 100);
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you just use regular CSS? Like:

```
.k-edit-form-container .k-textbox,
.k-edit-form-container .k-widget
{
    width: 600px;
}
```

You just have to make the selectors be a bit more specific that Kendo's built-in ones.

Comment: No, it is not working, I am using a template for the modal window, I tried to do like,                                                 var ComboBox = $("#ComboBox").data("kendoComboBox");
ComboBox.refresh();

Answer (score -2):

You can just delete the "parent"

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $(".k-edit-form-container")
        .width(800)
        .height(400)
        .data("kendoWindow")
        .center();
}, 100);
```